# How to make a button open a new activity

Tags: java, android

I want to know how to make a button open a new activity when pressed, for example:

I have my first activity and it has buttons I want each button to open up a new activity

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: try using `Context.startActivity()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android image button open new activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521485/android-image-button-open-new-activity)

Comment: its not duplicate :/ i want an actual button not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set onClickListener on button in which onClick method start your activity using intent.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   void onClick(View v) {
    Intent startA = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityToStart.class);
    startActivity(startA);   } });
```